# Check if a file exists in HDFS from Python

Tags: python, hadoop, fabric

So, I've been using the fabric package in Python to run shell scripts for various HDFS tasks.

However, whenever I run tasks to check if a file / directory already exists in HDFS, it simply quits the shell. Here is an example (I am using Python 3.5.2 and Fabric3==1.12.post1)

```
from fabric.api import local


local('hadoop fs -stat hdfs://some/nonexistent/hdfs/dir/')
```

If the directory does not exist, this code yields

> [localhost] local: hadoop fs -stat hdfs://some/nonexistent/hdfs/dir/
>   stat: `hdfs://some/nonexistent/hdfs/dir/': No such file or directory
>
> Fatal error: local() encountered an error (return code 1) while
>   executing 'hadoop fs -stat hdfs://some/nonexistent/hdfs/dir/'
>
> Aborting.

I also tried `local('hadoop fs -test -e hdfs://some/nonexistent/hdfs/dir/')` but it caused the same issue.

How can I use fabric to generate a boolean variable that will tell me whether or not a directory or file exists in hdfs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just check the `succeeded` flag of the result object returned from `local`.

```
from fabric.api import local
from fabric.context_managers import settings

file_exists = False
with settings(warn_only=True):
    result = local('hadoop fs -stat hdfs://some/nonexistent/hdfs/dir/', capture=True)
    file_exists = result.succeeded
```